# Get all entries from facebook groups feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the complete feed of a facebook group? I can get the feed group´s posts from

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/962582957103509/feed
```

But I can´t get all the entries. I can get some entries or use limit for showing more, but I want to download the complete feed with cron in my server, use this feed on my domain and use it as a file for paginating results without calling the url of **graph.facebook ...** each time. If I can download the whole feed to my domain, I can show these entries more quickly, and with cron I can keep the feed updated.

Comment: You need to use pagination and step through them.

Answer (score 0):

graph api response contains **pagination urls** at the end .

```
 "paging": {
    "previous": link here,
     "next": link here
  }
```

you will need to iterate through the feed using the pagination links, and download the feed contents.

Facebook docs page for [group/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed)